# Hardware and Software Search button in Android

Tags: java, android

I've implemented search functionality as explained in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html. This works fine on Android 2.3.5 with the hardware search button. Now I wonder how I could integrate a software search button. I added a button in the `ActionBar` but now I wonder how you can show a dialog for inputting the query as with the dialog showing up after pressing the hardware button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onOptionsItemSelected` method, check if the user pressed your search button.
If so, call the method `onSearchRequested()` in your `Activity`, and your custom search implementation should pop up.